# Cargar una imagen en Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Estoy intentando mostrar una imagen en Vue, pero me tira un error:

> **./assets/logo.png in
>   ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"0a514e76-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--18-0!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/background.vue?vue&type=template&id=45fa5c3e&**

Probe con `v-bind:src`, importando la imagen, pero no hay caso. Mi código:

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
      <img src="./assets/logo.png" alt="">
    </v-container>
 </template>
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a cerrar el tag de la imagen? (Poner una barra al final) Con algunos preprocesadores a veces falla la compilación si el html no es válido `<img src="./assets/logo.png" alt=""/>`

Comment: También viendo el error parece que que no llega a logo.png, ¿Podría ser un problema de rutas relativas? ¿Has probado una imagen con ruta absoluta para ver si te la carga?

Answer (score 1):

prueba con:

```
<img v-bind:src="require('./assets/logo.png')" alt="">
```

Lo que importaría la imagen, y es lo representa el v-bind.

---

Sino anda, importa este modulo:

[File Loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader)

En rules de webpack agregar:

```
 {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]?[hash]',
 }
```

Y podrás cargar archivos.

```
<img src="./assets/img/logo.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

los resolvi con esto compa no se si te sirva le tienes que poner el @ y guardar tu imagen en assets

```
<template>

 <div class="">
     <v-container grid-list-md>
         <v-layout row wrap>
             <v-flex xs0 xl6 lg6 md6 sm6>
                 
              <v-img src="@/assets/ic.png"></v-img>

             </v-flex>
               <v-flex xs0 xl6 lg6 md6 sm6>

                   <h2>halo</h2>
               </v-flex>
         </v-layout>

     </v-container>

 </div>
  
</template>

<script>
export default { 
} 

</script>
```

Comment: No explicas donde está el error ni cómo esta respuesta soluciona la consulta del OP.

Answer (score -2):

Prueba con esto:

```
<img v-bind:src="/assets/logo.png" />
```

Comment: Estimado, gracias por tu respuesta pero te recomiendo ver [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ya que publicar solo código sin la explicación esta en contra de las normas de la comunidad. Evita además que tengas calificación negativa y que borren tu respuesta.